# is "k" a variable in this case?

Tags: java, loops

In the following question, it states to only use a variable "n":

> Given an `int` variable `n` that has already been declared and
> initialized to a positive value, use a while loop to print a single
> line consisting of `n` asterisks. Use no variables other than `n`.

And here is the answer, which includes a variable `k`:

```
int k = 0;
while (k <= (n - 1)) {
    System.out.printf("*") ;
    k += 1;
}
```

Why is this correct? I thought the guidelines for the question on how to use no variables other than `n`?

Comment: yes, it is; your solution doesn't satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Addition is not the only operation that you can do in loops.

Comment: it is definitely wrong solution, probably they wanted something along `while (n-- > 0) System.out.print("*");`

Comment: I used to teach Java for a living.  I can assure you, teachers make mistakes sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question, yes, that's a new variable and the answer shouldn't be valid.

Regarding the solution: The trick is not doing an addition (you will need a new variable for sure to do that), but to perform a **decrement** operation `--` (which is an equivalent of subtracting `1`) instead:

```
//int n = 100 

while (n > 0)
{
   System.out.print("*");
   n--;
}
```